# CodeIgniter: Store last activity into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, session

I have created two tables in database, one with users and the other with sessions. I thought that there wouldn't be any problem with storing last activity into sessions, but then I found out that sessions are deleting and I somehow can't store last activity. Because I'd like to have last activity stored somewhere I need a solution how can I save it into users table on about five minutes - same as CodeIgniter change it's session data.

So, how to do that?

Comment: turn on db_session in config

Comment: i've already done that, because all of session data goes to session table.

Comment: What is your goal? I know you want to track user activity, but why? What is the tracking data for? How will you use it? How long will you keep it? You have talked about your implementation, but seeing all the comments below, it seems like we could help you more if we understood the underlying goals. The reason I say this is because from the comments from Murch, I am wondering if you are not going about it the best way.

Comment: @colonelclick: WesleyMurch solved my problem, so thank you for asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget the session table, just update the users table on each request. I'd do this in the constructor of your base controller so it runs automatically (see [`MY_Controller` examples](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) if you aren't familiar with this). Something like this:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct():
        // The session class is available now because
        // we called the parent constructor, where it is already loaded.

        // Get the current logged in user (however your app does it)
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        // You might want to validate that the user exists here

        // If you only want to update in intervals, check the last_activity.
        // You may need to load the date helper, or simply use time() instead.
        $time_since = now() - $this->session->userdata('last_activity');
        $interval = 300;

        // Do nothing if last activity is recent
        if ($time_since < $interval) return;

        // Update database
        $updated = $this->db
              ->set('last_activity', now())
              ->where('id', $user_id)
              ->update('users');

        // Log errors if you please
        $updated or log_message('error', 'Failed to update last activity.');
    }

}
```

To use this base controller, you will extend it with your other controllers. Example:

```
class SomeController extends MY_Controller {

    // MY_Controller constructor runs automatically

    function index()
    {
        // your code
    }

}
```

You might be able to do this in the same place where you initially fetch the logged in user user instead.

Comment: How to check last_activity on 5 minutes (so I can update db)? Is this controller able to access core libraries such as session and model (or it's better to create sql query inside this controller as you do)?

Comment: @user1257255 Put the last_activity (time) into a session variable. Then check the time difference against the current time on every request.

Comment: last_activity is already in variable from core library session. I need to know where to put code from Wesley, because I have more different controllers (it's possible that user won't open main controller and then there won't be stored right last activity) and at the same time I need to check value of last_activity before and now (so I can change it in DB). Can I extend library and put DB info directly into it? Can I use current model or I just have to put model's code ($this->db->...) into file?

Comment: @user1257255 This is just for *logged in* users, right? You want to update the logged in user's record with a last_activity timestamp only if the last activity is more than 5 minutes ago? Is that correct? I'm just not sure what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Yes, this is just for logged in users. I want to update user's last activity on X minutes (X = time which is set in config file for renewing session id). The main problem which I have is that I don't know where should I put your code, because I have more different controllers. There is possibilty that users wouldn't open controller in which would be mentioned code, so I'm looking for some global solution - maybe extending session library.

Comment: You use this controller as your base controller, then have all other controllers extend it. `class SomeController extends MY_Controller {}`. Do you understand? Do you need help calculating the X minutes?

Comment: Added some more info and examples, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, wouldn't it be better just to log to a different table? The interval will help, but still ;).  Also, it doesn't look like the session value gets updated, i.e. `$this->session->set_userdata('last_activity', now());`

Comment: @landons `last_activity` is populated automatically by the session class, and it's not clear why logging to a table other than the users table would be "better". The interval just reduces the number of requests that run an update.

Comment: @Wesley Correct me if I am wrong, but I think your example may not be as clear is it could be to someone learning CI because it is not extending an existing controller.

Comment: @colonelclick Yeah you're right I wasn't extending the base controller, thanks. I'm not sure what else the OP is looking for here... thanks for your comments.

Comment: @user1257255 How else can I help you? I know you're looking for more detail per your recent bounty offer, but I'm not sure what you're having trouble with. Maybe you could update your post with more of your own details, that would help you get a more helpful answer.

Comment: landons,colonelclick: Thank you for joining with helpful questions! @WesleyMurch: That's all :) Thank you very much for your time, examples and explanation!